# $H^s$-mild solution for Navier–Stokes : why do we restrict attention to the function spaces "without Fourier zero mode"? (Related to Terence Tao blog)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, navier-stokes

This question has been triggered by the Definition 32 and Remark 33 in the [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/254a-notes-1-local-well-posedness-of-the-navier-stokes-equations/) of Terence Tao.

There, every function space is restricted to ones without the Fourier zeroth mode. And the Remark 33 says that estimates become "slightly less favorable" if we do not exclude the zeroth mode.

I do not see clearly what becomes "less favorable". For example, no proof in the blog seems to rely on the Poincaré inequality at all.

In other words, all the proofs, theorems and exercises that follow Definition 32 and Remark 33 hold "equally valid" even if we do NOT exclude the Fourier zeroth mode in the function spaces?

Could anyone (hopefully the author himself) please clarify for me?

P.S. I am deeply grateful for Terence Tao for his extremely informative blogs.

Comment: He responds to questions on his blog, you can try asking there

Comment: @kodlu Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: I think you can see an answer to this intuitively by solving the equation for heat flow with separation of variables.